# Angular: Input with a default value that cannot be cleared

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am new working with angular and I have this code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" 
  class="col-30" id="mat-identifier">
  <mat-label>
    {{'columns.dashboard.identifier' | translate}} {{selectedIdentifier?.mandatorieIdentifier ? '*' : ''}}
  </mat-label>
  <input matInput [value]="selectedIdentifier?.standardIdentifier" 
    formControlName="identifier" maxlength="255" 
    (input)="limitcarateres('identifier', 255, $event)">
  <mat-hint *ngIf="showPackage!=true && selectedIdentifier && selectedIdentifier?.tag !== 'OTHERS'">
  {{
    selectedIdentifier?.standardIdentifier + 
    (dataCorrespondenceForm.get('identifier').value !== null  && dataCorrespondenceForm.get('identifier').value !== '' 
     ?  '-' + dataCorrespondenceForm.get('identifier').value : '')
  }}
  </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want this input to show a default value equal to the variable I am using but this value cannot be deleted by the user, the user should be able to write from this default value but not be able to delete it, assuming that the # are the default values and the numbers are the values added by the user, it should be seen like this
####123456
The numbers can be deleted but the # cannot, since the numbers were entered by the user

Comment: ok, how do you imagine it can be done? You've stated the problem but need to show some effort on your part to figure it out. I see you have an `input` listener. I would start with that.

Comment: Try adding #### as static content outside the text field.

Comment: if you use formControlName **not** use [value]. You should give value to the formControl when you create or using [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue) or [pathValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#patchvalue) the whole FormGroup

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the below CSS, we can add a span containing the placeholder then absolutely position it relative to the container, then the input element of the matInput will have padding so that the prefix remains constant!

```
.placeholder-prefix .mat-mdc-form-field-input-control{
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.placeholder-prefix .prefix{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 29px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.placeholder-prefix .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
  display: flex;
}

.mat-focused.placeholder-prefix .prefix{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 24px;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

html

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" class="placeholder-prefix">
    <span class="prefix">XXXX</span>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" id="test" name="test" />
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/yn9bws?file=src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss)

Answer (score 0):

next to the working pure HTML/CSS solution posted by @naren-murali, you could also use a mask. for example `ngx-mask`.
-> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

it has a `prefix` implementation which is what you would need here.

If you just have one place where you need such an implementation, you might better go with a pure HTML/CSS solution, but if you need similar functionality on multiple places you might want go give ngx-mask a try.